# ubuntu 19.04 wifi very slow - was alright for a couple of months

Tags: wireless, internet, 19.04

Suddenly the wifi has become unbearably slow.
This was running OK before with the same 19.04

Have tried changing wifi dongle without any success

LAN connection is not affected

Dongle tried:
  Tenda
  Edimax
  Netis WF2111

Answer (score 0):

If the dongle and your normal wifi both fail, it's probably not your computer but your router that is not functioning properly. Try restarting your router, move closer to it, etc.

This is too general a question in my opinion so I cant provide a less general answer for you either :( Hope it helps tho :)

Comment: Windows works fine with the same hardware, used to work fine in ubuntu before updates, some thing has been cripled by an update